# Jenkins build fails, then passes, then fails again

Tags: ros, jenkins, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to release a package and the Jenkins build [failed initially.](http://build.ros.org/job/Ibin_uS32__gauges__ubuntu_saucy_i386__binary/2/)

I committed some changes to fix the build, and it [eventually passed.](http://build.ros.org/job/Idev__gauges__ubuntu_trusty_amd64/5/changes)

But I'm still getting emails about [failed builds](http://build.ros.org/job/Ibin_uT64__gauges__ubuntu_trusty_amd64__binary/3/), which I think are coming from the earlier commits. Should I just ignore those, since the latest commit passes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247894/jenkins-build-fails,-then-passes,-then-fails-again/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2016-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have released a certain version of your repository (tagged and ran `bloom`). That state is what the binary jobs are processing.

You have then committed modification which are only being used by the devel jobs (which are building your development branch).

In order for the release jobs (which are still failing since they still build be previously released code) to use the new code you have to tag a new version and do a new release with `bloom`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2